# Is it possible to use an array of values in a jQuery Knob?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to use an array of values for my knob values.
Like: `20,30,60,100,200,400,800`

Is that possible?

https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible. However you can make it work.

If you set `step` to `1`, `min` to `0`, and `max` to your array length - 1, then in the `format` function you can get the element from the array at the selected index and return that value to be displayed within the knob. Try this:

```js
var values = [20, 30, 60, 100, 200, 400, 800];

$(".foo").knob({
  min: 0,
  max: values.length - 1,
  step: 1,
  format: function(v) {
    return values[v];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Knob/1.2.13/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="foo" value="0" />
```

Comment: Wow that;s a quick response and a nice solution! I just found a workaround with a switch statement but this is much nicer. Thanks!